# School printer configuration on personal device

Tags: macos, printing, settings, configuration-profiles

My school laptop has an option called "Secure_Printing" where the documents can be printed out on any school printer after inputting the student card number.

Here is the configuration in the System Report:

[image: Screenshot of a Mac System Report showing the 'Secure_Printing' configuration]

Is there a way to replicate the configuration on my personal Mac so that I can use the printers?

Answer (score 6):

Having managed this type of setup for years, I can assure you that you can't take a "published" secure printing certificate and just copy to other devices allowing you to print using school resources.

The URI that you obfuscated is unique to your Mac and installed peripherals.   If you copy over this file the URI will no longer match when authenticated against the printserver. To make it work, you'll need to register the computer(s) but given they are personal and not institutional, they likely won't be registered.

Comment: If they have to enter their student card number before printing anyway, there's chance their personal device gets approved so it might be worth trying.